Allowed blocks for core/column
I'm new to the world of Gutenberg blocks. A customer has a special need to restrict the allowed blocks that can be used inside core/column block. The editor should only be able to select a small part of the blocks that Wordpress provides to the user. Is there a way (e.g. hook or CSS code) where this can be achieved?

https://developer.wordpress.org/news/2024/01/29/how-to-disable-specific-blocks-in-wordpress/
I think this is a pretty common procedure the a lot of devs use when building blocks.

If you're using WordPress 6.5+, then you can filter the column blocks settings and add allowedBlocks array to it. In the array you'd define all the blocks, which the user can insert into the column.
wp.hooks.addFilter( 'blocks.registerBlockType', 'my-column-blocks', ( settings, name ) => {
  if ( name === 'core/column' ) {
    const { allowedBlocks = [] } = settings;
    return { ...settings, allowedBlocks: [ ...allowedBlocks, 'core/paragraph' ] };
  }
  return settings;
} );

